# gitlab CI dependency availability between stages

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have 7 stages in my pipeline. I need ruby for 3 of the stages.
things I have tried two different options,

1. Install ruby on each of the required stage,
2. Install ruby as part of the before_script section

Using before_script takes up too much of time trying to install ruby on the 4 other stages that does not require it.

Is there a way to do install dependencies as part of one stage and carry it forward for rest of the stages.

example yml

```
image: ubuntu:21.10

before_script:
 - apt update
 - apt install ruby-full
 - apt install python3.8

stages:          
 - s1
 - s2
 - s3
 - s4

s1:
  stage: s1
  script: ruby s1.rb

s2:
  stage: s2
  script: ruby s2.rb

s3:
  stage: s3
  script: python3 s3.py

s4:
  stage: s4
  script: python3 s4.py
```

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com shared runners or your own self-hosted runners? If self-hosted, please provide your runner configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few elements here to understand. Generally, every job starts with the same fresh environment. The only differences to this would be files passed through `artifacts:` or files restored from `cache:` configurations. Actions performed in one job generally otherwise have no effect on any other jobs.

> Using before_script takes up too much of time trying to install ruby on the 4 other stages that does not require it.

It's also important to know that `before_script` can be set for each job independently. If one job doesn't need it, just override the `before_script:` key in that job.

Anyhow. There are a few ways you might optimize your build speed with respect to dependencies:

### Docker image containing your dependencies

Typically, you would just use a ruby image as your `image:` for jobs requiring ruby. Usually an official image from dockerhub will work, like `ruby:3.1-alpine`.

```yaml
some_ruby_job:
  image: "ruby:3.1-alpine"
  script:  # ruby is already available by default
    - echo "hello ruby"
    - ruby -v

some_other_job:
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - echo "this job does not need ruby"
```

#### Making a custom docker image

If your dependencies are very complex, you may even choose to create your own docker images and push them to the project's container registry so you can use the custom image with all your dependencies as your `image:`.

You could even build an image in one stage and use it as the `image:` in subsequent stages. This example uses [docker caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-caching-example) with `--cache-from` to further speed up that process.

```yaml
build:
  image: docker:19.03.12
  stage: .pre
  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY/group/project/image:$CI_BRANCH_NAME || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY/group/project/image:$CI_BRANCH_NAME -t $CI_REGISTRY/group/project/image:$CI_BRANCH_NAME .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/group/project/image:$CI_BRANCH_NAME

some_ruby_job:
  stage: test
  # This is the image that was built in the previous stage!
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/group/project/image:$CI_BRANCH_NAME
  script:
    - echo "all my dependencies are here!"
    - ruby -v
```

### Caching

To further speed things along, you may also choose to [cache your ruby dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-ruby-dependencies) (say, if you install gems as part of your job)
Something like:

```yaml
some_ruby_job:
  stage: one
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - Gemfile.lock
    paths:
      - vendor/ruby
  # ...
```

That way the `vendor/ruby` directory is cached which will avoid the need to download the gems again in every stage.

#### Cache policy

You can also speed up caching behavior in subsequent stages by setting the [cache policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cachepolicy) to `pull` (to avoid time spent uploading the cache after the job). In other words, only one job is responsible for generating the cache, the other jobs reuse the same cache.

```
ruby_jobs_in_future_stages:
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - Gemfile.lock
    paths:
      - vendor/ruby
    policy: pull # only download the cache, don't upload it
```

Comment: I am not dealing with one dependency, but with multiple. I have updated with an example

Comment: @user11547433 I believe the answer still covers this use case. As stated, you (1) don't have to have `before_script:` applied to all jobs and (2) you can use images with your dependencies included.